# how to parse weird string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to parse following string in javascript or jquery

```
var str = "(obj.userAge EQUALS  "51") AND (obj.userAddress CONTAINS "STREET1 (SOUTH)") OR (obj2.salary >= "3000.12")";
```

output like following.

```
obj
userAge
EQUALS
51
AND
obj
userAddress
CONTAINS
STREET1 (SOUTH)
OR
obj2
salary
>=
3000.12
```

I tried with `str.split();` and with yet another `split` of `split`, but I am not getting above result.

Comment: The initial "string" you provided is not a valid JavaScript code, shouldn't it be surrounded in single quotes and not double?

Comment: Yes. I know. But I am getting that string from the database.

Comment: You don't get the surrounding quotes from database?! This way it cannot be executed.

Comment: believe me. I am storing such string from javascript. When I see database row I can see string with double quotes. And also it is required from my project-requirement point of view

Comment: The data in your **database is ok**, but **the code you provided isn't**. To be valid it should be either surrounded in single quotes (like in answer by Arun) or double quotes should be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative

```
var str = '(obj.userAge EQUALS  "51") AND (obj.userAddress CONTAINS "STREET1") OR (obj2.salary >= "3000")';

console.log(str.replace(/[()]/g, "").split(/[\. ]/));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Ukxg9/)

And both the accepted method and the above will have a problem if you address has a space in it, like "STRE ET1" or if address or the numbers contain a period "."

but this should fix those problems

```
var str = '(obj.userAge EQUALS  "51") AND (obj.userAddress CONTAINS "STR EET1.SOME WHERE") OR (obj2.salary >= "3000")';

console.log(str.replace(/[()]/g, "").match(/(?:[^\s\."]+|"[^"]*")+/g));
```

On jsfiddle

Both of the above would still have a problem if the address contains "(" or ")", that could be fixed too, the following should fix it.

```
var str = '(obj.userAge EQUALS  "51") AND (obj.userAddress CONTAINS "STR EET1.()SOME WHERE") OR (obj2.salary >= "3000")';

console.log(str.match(/(?:[^\s\.()"]+|"[^"]*")+/g));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/qj7gd/)

No need to ignore any returned empty string ("") with these methods

And for interest sake a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/split-sql-query) of all the methods

Answer (score 2):

Use a regex to split it

```
var str = '(obj.userAge EQUALS  "51") AND (obj.userAddress CONTAINS "STREET1") OR (obj2.salary >= "3000")';
var parts = str.split(/[\s\.\(\)]/)
```

Then ignore all `""` strings

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9eMgL/)

Comment: This will have problems if the address contains a space, or the address, age, or salary contain a period.